# Haskell: Order of evaluation for (++) and (:) operators

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have the following Haskell expression:

```
3 : [40] ++ [50] ++ 5 : [60]
```

I would like to know how this expression is evaluated. Which operator has a higher precedence, `:` or `++`?
I think the result of the expression is [3,40,50,5,60], however I did this the following way:

```
3 : [40] ++ [50] ++ 5 : [60]
3 : [40] ++ [50] ++ [5,60]
3 : [40] ++ [50,5,60]
3: [40,50,5,60]
[3,40,50,5,60]
```

Is the above the correct way to evaluate the expression? Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: A common misunderstanding is to consider operator precedence to be the same as evaluation order. In `f 1 + f 2 * f 3` precedence requires that the multiplication is performed first than the addition, but that does not impose any evaluation order between `f 1`, `f 2`, `f 3`. In a pure language like Haskell, the evaluation order is mostly irrelevant to the final result (albeit it can affect performance, in some cases).

Answer (score 9):

Both the [**`(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-43--43-) and **`(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]`** function have **`5`** as *precedence*, as we can read in the [*Haskell '10 report*](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#dx10-82001), and are right associative.

We can also obtain this data with `:i` in the `ghci` shell:

```
Prelude> :i (:)
data [] a = ... | a : [a]       -- Defined in ‘GHC.Types’
infixr 5 :
Prelude> :i (++)
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]       -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
infixr 5 ++
```

This thus means that:

```
3 : [40] ++ [50] ++ 5 : [60]
```

is short for:

```
3 : ([40] ++ ([50] ++ (5 : [60])))
```

The `(++)` operator is [implemented as](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#%2B%2B):

> ```
> (++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
> (++) []     ys = ys
> (++) (x:xs) ys = x : xs ++ ys
> ```

The `(:)` is a data constructor, so that means it can not be "further evaluated".

This makes sense since it thus means that the `++` is here only applied to the tail, and hence as long as we are interested in the head, we do not need to evaluate that function. So a right associative `(++)` is usually cheaper than a left associative `(++)` although it will result in the same list.

If we thus want to evaluate the full list, it is evaluated as:

```
   3 : ([40] ++ ([50] ++ (5 : [60])))
-> 3 : (40 : ([] ++ ([50] ++ (5 : [60]))))
-> 3 : (40 : ([50] ++ (5 : [60])))
-> 3 : (40 : (50 : ([] ++ (5 : [60]))))
-> 3 : (40 : (50 : (5 : [60])))
```

or more verbose:

```
   3 : ((40: []) ++ ((50 : []) ++ (5 : (60 : []))))
-> 3 : (40 : ([] ++ ((50 : []) ++ (5 : (60 : [])))))
-> 3 : (40 : ((50 : []) ++ (5 : (60 : []))))
-> 3 : (40 : (50 : ([] ++ (5 : (60 : [])))))
-> 3 : (40 : (50 : (5 : (60 : []))))
```

Comment: @ceno980: no, note that Haskell is lazy, furthermore `(:)` is a *data constructor*, so that means that can not be further evaluated. `[60]` is just syntactical sugar for `60 : []`, just like `[1,4,2,5]` is syntactical sugar for `(1:4:2:5:[])`.

Comment: I don't fully understand the above explanation. Am I correct in saying that the expression in the rightmost set of parentheses is evaluated first e.g. (5 : [60])? I also don't understand the line: 3 : (40 : ([ ] ++ ([50] ++ (5 : [60])))) - why did you introduce the : operator after the 40, and place a [ ] ++ before the 50?

Comment: @ceno980: because that is how `(++)` is implemented, see edit. The second rule fires, so if the first argument is `(50:[])` then the second clause fires.

Comment: “...as you can read in the Haskell '10 report...” – except nobody that. Why don't you explain about `:i`?

Comment: Haskell often appears to have an inversion of evaluation order compared to strict languages. The *outside* of an expression is generally evaluated first: `[50] ++ ([10] ++ [5])` has `[50] ++ _etc` on the outside, so it evaluates to `50 : ([10] ++ [5])`, and then the outer `(:)`, because it is a data constructor, gives you a chance to stop evaluating. You can choose to stop, or you can continue deeper and finish with `50 : 10 : 5 = [50, 10, 5]`. In something like Python, it would happen backwards: `[50] ++ ([10] ++ [5])` -> `[50] ++ [10, 5]` -> `[50, 10, 5]`, but this isn't Python.